# How to extend xs:list in XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I am learning how to write XML schemas and I would like to define an XML schema to validate an XML construct like this:

```
<mylist myattr="1">1 2 3 4 5 6 7</mylist>
```

I therefore tried to define a `complexType` that makes use of `list` and has one attribute.

This is the schema I came up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:complexType name="mylist-type">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:list" >
        <xs:attribute name="myattr" type="xs:integer"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="mylist" type="mylist-type"/>
</xs:schema>
```

When I validate the XML against the schema using http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html, I obtain the error

```
Src-resolve.4.2: Error Resolving Component 'xs:list'. 
It Was Detected That 'xs:list' Is In Namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', 
But Components From This Namespace Are Not Referenceable From Schema Document 'null'.
If This Is The Incorrect Namespace, Perhaps The Prefix Of 'xs:list' Needs To Be Changed.
If This Is The Correct Namespace, Then An Appropriate 'import' Tag Should Be Added To null'.
```

However, if I simply change `xs:list` to `xs:string`, the schema validates without problems, which for me raised the question whether it is really a namespace issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you want a string list, (eg. `<x>1 2 3 4</x>`, instead of an actual list of elements `<x><y>1</y><y>2</y>...`? The latter is more verbose, but allows you to leverage the structure of XML easier down the track, instead of having to de-serialise the XML and then process the string.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will keep it in mind for the future. At the moment I am writing a schema for an existing XML format that stores (amongst other things) blocks of data and is in the end parsed with Fortran, i.e. here it is probably not a viable option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:simpleType name="int-list">
     <xs:list itemType="xs:integer"/>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:complexType name="mylist-type">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="int-list" >
        <xs:attribute name="myattr" type="xs:integer"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="mylist" type="mylist-type"/>
</xs:schema>
```

so basically first define a particular list type, then use that list type in your extension.

Answer (score 0):

Your draft schema defines `mylist-type` as an extension of the type `xs:list`.  But there is no datatype named `list` in the XSD namespace.  The reason the error goes away when you substitute the name `xs:string` is there *is* a type named xs:string.

When your processor tells you "Perhaps The Prefix Of 'xs:list' Needs To Be Changed", it's guessing that perhaps you meant a `list` type in some other namespace.

[Addendum]  What *is* xs:list, you ask, if it's not a type?  It's one of three methods of deriving simple types from other simple types.  For example, the following type declaration describes a list of integers, separated by white space.  The `itemType` attribute on the xs:list element says what type the items of the list have.

```
<xs:simpleType name="list-of-integer">
  <xs:list itemType="xs:integer"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

As is usual in XSD, an anonymous type may also be used instead of a named type; in that case, the relevant simpleType element appears as a child of xs:list.  In the following declaration, the inner simpleType element declares a type whose values are the integers from 0 to 100, inclusive (e.g. the scale of grades used on quizzes in a course), and the outer simpleType element declares a type consisting of a list of such numbers.

```
<xs:simpleType name="list-of-grades">
  <xs:list>
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="100"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:list>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Thank you for your explaining **why** the error arises! Could you maybe add what xs:list **is** (or where it is found), if it is not a datatype in the XSD namespace?